# What happens to malloced data in a struct in C when it is assigned to another variable?

Tags: c, struct, malloc, heap-memory, stack-memory

Let's say I have a structure named "example" which has a member named data which stores data allocated on the heap:

```
typedef struct _EXAMPLE
{
    signed char *data;
    size_t size;
} example_t;

example_t *example_alloc(size_t size)
{
    example_t *ret = malloc(sizeof *ret);
    ret->size = size;
    ret->data = calloc(size, sizeof *ret->data);

    return ret;
}

example_t *a = example_alloc(10), b = *a;
```

Is the value in `b.data` stored on the stack or the heap? Does it point to the data in `a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointers are just values.

In the same way that `b.size` is just a copy of `a->size`, `b.data` is a copy of the same pointer value that `a->data` holds.

It points to the same location, wherever that may be.

Care must be taken, as `free`ing `a->data` invalidates `b.data`, and vice versa, which may result in [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) if accessed.

Answer (score 1):

The structure `b` is a local variable, and all its members are stored locally in the stack (please, no pedantic comments saying that C doesn't specify that there's a stack -- it requires something that acts like a stack).

Since `b.data` is a member of `b`, it's stored on the stack. However, the data that it points to is the same as what `a->data` points to, and that's the heap memory that was allocated with `calloc()` in the function.

Answer (score 1):

Following `b = *a`, `a->data == b.data`.  That is to say they both refer to the same allocated memory.  This is known as a "*shallow copy*".  To achieve a *"deep copy"* in C would require additional code.  For example:

```
example_t* example_copy( example_t* b, const example_t* a )
{
    *b = *a ; // shallow copy all members
    
    // Allocate new block and copy content
    size_t sizeof_block = b->size * sizeof(*b->data)
    b->data = malloc( sizeof_block ) ;
    memcpy( b->data, a->data, sizeof_block ) ;

    return b ;
}
```

Then

```
example_t *a = example_alloc(10) ;
example_t b ;
example_copy( &b, a ) ;
```

Note that such code is is horribly prone to memory leaks.  Here for example if `b` goes out of scope before `b.data` is `free`'d, you will have lost access to that memory.  Any function that allocates memory and returns without having `free`'d it is making it the caller's responsibility whilst not at all making that necessarily visible or obvious (your naming convention `_alloc` is some level of mitigation perhaps). You should at least also implement corresponding functions to facilitate the clean-up of objects.  I appreciate that it is an off-topic point but C++ provides a solution to this issue  where a destructor is invoked when an object goes out of scope.  Additionally copy constructors and assignment operator overloading can be used to automatically invoke *deep-copy* semantics.